# CSS cross browser change layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem with my CSS design when I try at other browser:

so far I make this at [Mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rokm9.png)

[image]

The left bar and content fit into browser screen

but when I tried at [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETvfn.png)

[image]

i tried to delete the content and become like this (no scroll, but still have some spaces):

[image]

the design changed, I dont know why this happening , because I only started to try CSS design and dont have any experiece :( ANy one can help me fix this?

Coding:

```
#containerLeft
{
    z-index: -1;
}

#leftcolumn {

    height:100%;
    background-repeat:none;
    z-index:100;
}
.bottom {
    margin: none;
    width: 180px;
    height: 17px;
}
ul {
    background-image: url(SlicingImage/action_bar.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: left;
    float:left;
}
li {
    list-style:none;
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
}
.separator {
    background-image:url(SlicingImage/separator.png);
    background-position:center;
    width:171px;
    /*select your width */
    height:5px;
    /*select your height */
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.buttons {
    display:block;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#FFF;
    background-image:url(SlicingImage/button_unselect.png);
    margin: none;
    height: 53px;
    width: 180px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
    line-height:53px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="containerleft">
   <div id="leftcolumn">
    <ul>
            <p><img src="SlicingImage/alacards_logo.png"/>

            <li class="separator"></li>            
            <a href="#" id="home" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            home
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <a href="#" id="user" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example2');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            users
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <a href="#" id="tutorial" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example3');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            tutorial
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <a href="#" id="issuer" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example4');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            issuers
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <a href="#" id="merchant" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example5');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            merchants
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <a href="#" id="partner" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example6');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            partners
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <a href="#" id="highlight" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example7');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            high light
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <a href="#" id="news" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example8');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            news
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li>
            <a href="#" id="contact" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example9');return false;"><li class="buttons">
            contact us
            </li></a>
            <li class="separator"></li> 
            </p>
         </ul>       
        </div>
       </div>
```

Body:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('slicingimage/background.jpg');
    background-repeat:none;
    background-size:100%;
    z-index:-1;
} 

body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#333
}
```

Comment: can you tell what are the styles you have written for your body tag

Comment: try including a css reset http://html5reset.org/ . This will normalize how your page looks across different browsers

Comment: Im using eric meyer reset.css and work fine, but if I try that link, change my design again... From what I see, I think my content (right column) that lowered, not my action bar, but I'm not sure again..

Answer (score 0):

Try by adding this in the body style

```
margin:0px; padding:0px;
```

Comment: still the same output at chrome :(

Comment: *sidenote:* 0 has no unit in CSS. no need to add `px` after `0`

Comment: Try by adding this styles to your main div -- overflow-y: hidden !important; overflow-x: auto !important;

Answer (score 0):

You have asked the leftColumn div to be height 100%, if it or the body have any margin or padding, it will take up over 100% and need scrollbars.

```
body, div  {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I would recommend using a [css reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/) to reduce such issues